# Как в Material Ui кастомизировать всплывающее меню Select?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Как в Material Ui кастомизировать стиль всплывающего меню компонента Select? Судя по доке, у него даже нет специального атрибута, в который можно было бы вставить свой Menu или Popper. Решение желательно для React.